# APScheduler doesn't work with UWSGI

Tags: python, django, nginx, apscheduler

I'm using Django 1.8 and APScheduler to run workers on certain intervals. It works perfectly with Django's development server (e.g. `./manage.py runserver`) but when I setup the project with UWSGI and `master=true`, the UWSGI worker can't get any requests from Nginx and browser shows `504 Gateway Timed-out` error after 1-2min loading.

When I change it to `master=false` everything is fine.

Here is my UWSGI config:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir             = /var/www/projectname/backend/projectname
module         = projectname.wsgi:application
wsgi-file        = /var/www/projectname/backend/projectname/projectname/wsgi.py
uid                = root
gid                = root
virtualenv     = /var/www/venv/
master          = false
processes    = 4
socket          = :8080
logto             = /var/www/projectname/log/uwsgi.log
env               = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=projectname.settings
enable-threads = true
```

Please note that I'm using Django's AppConfig to run the scheduler once. Is there any problem with my UWSGI config or it's because of Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider uWSGI mules for your background tasks. The workers handle requests, the mules handle longer running stuff.

Comment: The idea of a mule is a long running process, independent of the workers. You can run schedulers inside the mules.

Comment: Do mules have to just be enabled to use it in Django?  Does anything have to be done to the job registration in order to use a mule?

Comment: If you run dango in uWSGI, it's preferable to use uWSGI mules. Django may have its own background processes but these would replicate to the nr of uWSGI worker processes.